# How can I test if all bits are set or all bits are not?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Using bitwise operator how can I test if the n least significant bits of an integer are either all sets or all not sets.

For example `if n = 3` I only care about the 3 least significant bits the test should return true for 0 and 7 and false for all other values between 0 and 7.

Of course I could do `if x = 0 or x = 7`, but I would prefer something using bitwise operators.

Bonus points if the technique can be adapted to take into accounts all the bits defined by a mask.

Clarification :

If I wanted to test if bit one or two is set I could to `if ((x & 1 != 0) && (x & 2 != 0))`. But I could do the "more efficient" `if ((x & 3)  != 0)`.

I'm trying to find a "hack" like this to answer the question "Are all bits of x that match this mask all set or all unset?"

The easy way is `if ((x & mask) == 0 || (x & mask) == mask)`. I'd like to find a way to do this in a single test without the || operator.

Comment: What is the use case? Why do you want such a method

Comment: I'm got interested in bit manipulation hacks by reading here https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html and I'm trying to find a way to tests if all bits of a masked are either all 1 or all 0. It's just curiosity, I wonder if it can be done.

Comment: several answers make the mistake of writing `1 << n`.  This causes undefined behaviour if `n >= 31` (if you're on a 32-bit int system).  The `1` needs to be cast to be of unsigned type that is at least as wide as the value you are testing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Using bitwise operator how can I test if the n least significant bits of an integer are either all sets or all not sets.

To get a mask for the last `n` significant bits, thats

```
(1ULL << n) - 1
```

So the simple test is:

```
bool test_all_or_none(uint64_t val, uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t mask = (1ULL << n) - 1;
    val &= mask;
    return val == mask || val == 0;
}
```

If you want to avoid the `||`, we'll have to take advantage of integer overflow. For the cases we want, after the `&`, `val` is either `0` or (let's say n == 8) `0xff`. So `val - 1` is either `0xffffffffffffffff` or `0xfe`. The failure causes are `1` thru `0xfe`, which become `0` through `0xfd`. Thus the success cases are call at least `0xfe`, which is `mask - 1`:

```
bool test_all_or_none(uint64_t val, uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t mask = (1ULL << n) - 1;
    val &= mask;
    return (val - 1) >= (mask - 1);
}
```

We can also test by adding 1 instead of subtracting 1, which is probably the best solution (here once we add one to `val`, `val & mask` should become either `0` or `1` for our success cases):

```
bool test_all_or_none(uint64_t val, uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t mask = (1ULL << n) - 1;
    return ((val + 1) & mask) <= 1;
}
```

For an *arbitrary* mask, the subtraction method works for the same reason that it worked for the specific mask case: the `0` flips to be the largest possible value:

```
bool test_all_or_none(uint64_t val, uint64_t mask)
{
    return ((val & mask) - 1) >= (mask - 1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to test them separately. I want to test for both at the same time.

Comment: @MathieuPagé Came up with an even better one.

Comment: Nice one. This answer my original question where I wanted to test the n least significant bits. If we don't find a version that works for an arbitrary mask I'll accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Barry just came up with `((x+1)&mask)<=1;` independently; nice job!

Comment: @MathieuPagé The subtraction method works for an arbitrary mask - for the same reason it works for the specific n-bits one.

Comment: @jxh I think you misunderstood the question. It's not: `input == mask || input == 0`, it's `(input & mask) == mask || (input & mask) == 0`.

Comment: In all of this `1 << n` should be `(uint64_t)1 << n`. The literal `1` is an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

How about?

```
int mask = (1<<n)-1;
if ((x&mask)==mask || (x&mask)==0) { /*do whatever*/ }
```

The only really tricky part is the calculation of the mask.  It basically just shifts a 1 over to get `0b0...0100...0` and then subtracts one to make it `0b0...0011...1`.

Maybe you can clarify what you wanted for the test?

Comment: I wish to test it without using the || operator.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you wanted to do, in one function (untested, but you should get the idea). Returns 0 if the n last bits are not set, 1 if they are all set, -1 otherwise.

```
int lastBitsSet(int num, int n){
    int mask = (1 << n) - 1; //n 1-s
    if (!(num & mask)) //we got all 0-s
        return 0;
    if (!(~num & mask)) //we got all 1-s
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mints97, I'm looking for a way to do it in a single test. @Barry found a way to do it for the case where the mask cover the n lest significants bits.

Comment: @MathieuPagé: yes, but his method doesn't distinguish between the cases where the last bits are all set or all not set.

Comment: Indeed. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: @MathieuPagé: I'm sorry, I must have misunderstood your question then =)

Comment: @Mits97, that's ok. Someone else who land on this question in the future might wants to differentiate the two and your answer will be valuable to them.

Answer (score 0):

To test if all aren't set, you just need to mask-in only the bits you want, then you just need to compare to zero.

The fun starts when you define the oposite function by just inverting the input :)

```
//Test if the n least significant bits arent set:
char n_least_arent_set(unsigned int n, unsigned int value){
  unsigned int mask = pow(2, n) - 1; // e. g. 2^3 - 1 = b111
  int masked_value = value & mask;
  return masked_value == 0; // if all are zero, the mask operation returns a full-zero.      
}

//test if the n least significant bits are set:
char n_least_are_set(unsigned int n, unsigned int value){
  unsigned int rev_value = ~value;
  return n_least_arent_set(n, rev_value);    
}
```